# Displaying table using handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I have an array of strings
`const types = ['Day', 'Evening']`
and an object

```
const days = {
  Mon: [{count: 2, type: 'Day'}]
  Tue: [{count: 3, type: 'Evening'}, {count: 2, type: 'Day'},]
}
```

I would like to display the above data in a table by `types` and `days` using handlebars
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6hLF.png)

This is what I've got so far. I'm not sure how to reference the `days` inside the `types`'s mapping.

```
<table style="color: #000">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      {{#each types}}  
      <th style="padding: 2px 0">
        {{this}}
      </th>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
  {{#each days}}
  <tr>
    <td style="color: #000; border: 1px solid #000;">
     {{@key}}
    </td>

    {{#each types}}
     <td style="color: #000; border: 1px solid #000;">
       {{#equals days.type this }}
         {{days.count}}
       {{/equals}}
     </td>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
 </tbody>

</table>
```

Thanks for in advance your help!

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the shape of your `days` value? The fact that each day key (`Mon`, `Tue`) points to an array makes this your desired output more difficult to achieve. If it were like `Mon: { Day: { count: 2 } }`, it would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to change the shape of your `days` value so that each day key points to an object instead of an array. This object would have keys matching the `types` values. This will make a lookup much easier - for example, it is easier (and more performant) to lookup `Mon.Evening` rather than do an array operation like `Mon.find(value => value.type === 'Evening')`.

`days` would become:

```
const days = {
  Mon: {
    Day: {
      count: 2
    }
  },
  Tue: {
    Day: {
      count: 2
    },
    Evening: {
      count: 3
    }
  }
};
```

The piece of the template that renders the counts would become:

```
{{#each ../types}}
  <td style="color: #000; border: 1px solid #000;">
    {{lookup (lookup .. this) 'count'}}
  </td>
{{/each}}
```

Here, we are nesting calls to the Handlebars built-in [lookup](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) helper - which allows us to *lookup* the value at a key of an object. In the inner `lookup`, `..` is stepping-up a context level to get the day object; and `this` is the type - for example `(lookup { Day: { count: 2 } } 'Day')`, which would return the value at the `Day` key: `{ count: 2 }`. The outer `lookup` gets the `count` value of this object.

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('Template').innerHTML);

const days = {
  Mon: {
    Day: {
      count: 2
    }
  },
  Tue: {
    Day: {
      count: 2
    },
    Evening: {
      count: 3
    }
  }
};

const types = ['Day', 'Evening'];

const output = template({ days, types });

document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script id="Template" type="text/template">
<table style="color: #000">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      {{#each types}}  
        <th style="padding: 2px 0">
            {{this}}
        </th>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
  {{#each days}}
    <tr>
      <td style="color: #000; border: 1px solid #000;">
       {{@key}}
      </td>

      {{#each ../types}}
       <td style="color: #000; border: 1px solid #000;">
         {{lookup (lookup .. this) 'count'}}
       </td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
 </tbody>
</table>
</script>

<div id="Output"></div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/r6gmstau/) is the same code as above in a fiddle.

If you *cannot* alter the `days` variable, it is not impossible to get your desired result, but it is much uglier. You would need to create a custom helper to loop over the day value array to find the object whose `type` matches the `type` of the column.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/Lfzt52yh/) is a fiddle with that solution.